# Capture windows name in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a program in delphi that capture active windows the problem is that the code does not do what I want, what I want is a timer recognize active windows in due time such that attach the name of the active window and instead of showing eternally wait until you see one with a different name, the problem is that it always shows not doing what I want.
if problem is not that I do well the verification.

the code

```
procedure TForm1.Timer4Timer(Sender: TObject);

var
  ventana1: array [0 .. 255] of char;       
  nombre1: string;
  nombre2: String;

begin

  GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow, ventana1, SizeOf(ventana1));

  nombre1 := ventana1;

  if not(nombre1 = nombre2) then
  begin
    nombre2 := nombre1;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(nombre2);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what goes wrong and an example of what you're expecting? "Shows not doing what I want" isn't enough for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do nothing to initialize `nombre2`, so `nombre1 = nombre2` can never be true. `nombre2` is always `nil`.

Setting `nombre2 := nombre1;` in the `if` statement is also meaningless, as the value is immediately lost when the procedure exits; the next call of the timer event starts over with `nombre2 = nil` because `nombre2` is a new, local variable that is initialized to `nil` every time the procedure is entered, and it's released every time the procedure exits.

Move `nombre2` to a form instance variable instead:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    // normal declarations here
    procedure Timer4Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Nombre2: string;  // I'd use LastWindowName myself. :-)
  ...
  end;
```

Now, in your timer event:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer4Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  ventana1: array [0 .. 255] of char;       
  nombre1: string;  // I'd use 'NewName' 
begin
  GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow, ventana1, SizeOf(ventana1));

  nombre1 := ventana1;

  if not(nombre1 = nombre2) then  // Now nombre2 still has the last value,
  begin                           // because it's no longer a local variable
    nombre2 := nombre1;           // Store new "last window name"
    Memo1.Lines.Add(nombre2);
  end;
end
```